# Geolocation.getCurrentPosition from dart:html not working in release mode with NNBD enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, dart-null-safety

Does anybody know why the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` from `dart:html` doesn't work when running in release mode with sound null safety enabled (`flutter run --release -d chrome`)?

When making this call I do get an instance of `Geoposition` back but when I try to access one of it's members I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.grq is not a function
    at main.dart:39
    at WD.a (async_patch.dart:316)
    at WD.$2 (async_patch.dart:341)
    at VR.$1 (async_patch.dart:292)
    at UG.SB (zone.dart:1612)
    at UG.ug (zone.dart:1611)
    at Tf.$0 (future_impl.dart:118)
    at Object.n3 (future_impl.dart:733)
    at Y.ib (future_impl.dart:539)
    at T7.$0 (future_impl.dart:577)
```

If I run the same code in debug (`flutter run -d chrome` or without NNBD `flutter run -d chrome --release --no-sound-null-safety` everything works fine). A simple App that reproduces this behaviour looks like this (it's a slightly changed version of the default Flutter counter template):

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _position = "Unknown";

  Future<void> _currentPosition() async {
    final geolocation = html.window.navigator.geolocation;
    final position = await geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    final latitude = position.coords?.latitude ?? 'n/a';
    final longitude = position.coords?.longitude ?? 'n/a';
    setState(() {
      _position =
          'Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Your current position is:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_position',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _currentPosition,
        tooltip: 'Current position',
        child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in Dart. I have created a bug report which can be tracked here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45562